# How to press Enter button in winium

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests

I'm trying to automate the test of winform application. But I have small problem. I can't press Enter button on textbox.
So what I tried to do:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

Also I tried to insert the enter btn to my textbox, but this action simply delete my data in textbox.

I should write name and then press enter to make the textbox work, but i don't know how else i can press it because there is no tutorials about winium.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What programming language are you using with Winium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by using this command.

```
driver.findElementByClassName("Edit").sendKeys("{ENTER}");
```